# SSRS: Can I set text boxes etc to render with transparent backgrounds when viewing in IE 11?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I've created a report using Report Builder 3.0.

I've arranged several list data regions to display columns of information, and have used several horizontal dotted lines drawn over the top of the lists/columns to visually split each row of data.

The report page is white, the data regions have no fill, and the dotted lines are grey.

When viewed in report builder, the dotted lines are visible running over the top of the other items:

[image]

However, when I run the report in IE11, the dotted lines appear to sit behind the lists, with the lists apparently filled with solid white backgrounds that obscure the lines.

Are there any settings that can be used within report-builder to either: force the data regions to remain transparent in IE11, or, force the dotted lines (layers) to sit in the foreground? ...or is this another IE11 head banger?

I've tried all the options I can find in report builder to set fill settings to blank, and to sit the dotted lines in the foreground, but without success.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I bet increasing the padding by a pixel or three would fix the display issue?

Comment: @RossBush - I'm not sure how increasing the padding could have an effect on this? The List Data Regions run vertically as narrow columns.

Comment: Doh!, I just saw that there are faint lines visible in your image. I thought there were no lines at all.

Comment: Does it look OK in other browsers? IE is a bit of pig sometimes as you probably know.

Comment: I suspect probably fine in Chrome @AlanSchofield, but unfortunately not possible for me to check I'm afraid as we're restricted on our network to IE11 browser only (and consequently, the report end users will all be limited to IE11 also) :/

Comment: AH well, the only things I can suggest is to run IE in compatibility mode for this report and see if it makes any difference, it might be even worse!... but worth a quick test I guess. Other than that I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield. No joy unfortunately in compatibility view (thanks for the suggestion though). I've dropped our IT desk a line to see if I can persuade a Chrome install to test on. Failing that, it'll be back to the drawing board I think to get this displaying how I want it...

Comment: Tried it in Chrome now and it's still giving me the same issue. Think I'll have to come at it from a different angle and redesign around it. Thanks for your suggestion guys.